# join is giving duplicated in result set

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

We want to join on part#. the first table has most of the data we want. the second has sales data per part. the first table just browsing it gives this

```
TRUL02A           I          2,014    CRW                16.00-
CORGDFOIL         I          2,014    CRW             7,090.00-
FISTAS            I          2,014    CRW             5,716.00-
HWCR1             I          2,014    CRW            70,403.00-
HWFE1             I          2,014    CRW            52,317.00-
RO060             I          2,014    CRW            12,669.00-
MYCBOCB           I          2,014    CRW                66.00-
MY6BOCB           I          2,014    CRW                  .00 
MA20X3UL          I          2,014    CRW               167.00-
MA20X3CS1         I          2,014    CRW            72,978.00-
```

no dupes of part number but when join on the 
sales amt per part table we get duplicates.

```
SELECT                                                              
  ALL       T01.IAPRT#, T01.IA101, T01.IAPRLC, T01.IAUM, T01.IAPR$C,
T01.IARCC1,                                                     
T01.IARCC2, T01.IARCC3, T01.IARCC4, T01.IARCC5,                     
T01.IARCC6,                                                         
            T01.IARCC7, T01.IARCC8, T01.IARCC9, T01.IARC10,         
T01.IARC11,                                                         
            T01.IARC12, T01.IARC13, T01.IARC14, T01.IARC15,         
T02.IQYER#,                                                         
            T02.IQA01, T02.IQA02, T02.IQA03, T02.IQA04, T02.IQA05,  
T02.IQA06,                                                          
T02.IQA07, T02.IQA08, T02.IQA09, T02.IQA10, T02.IQA11,              
T02.IQA12,                                                          
T02.IQA13, T02.IQA14                                                
  FROM      ASTDTA.ICPRT1 T01 LEFT OUTER JOIN                       
            ASTDTA.ICSUM1 T02                                       
ON        T01.IAPRT# = T02.IQPRT#  

WHERE     IAORDF = '1'                      
  AND     IARCC6 = 'INV'                    
  AND     T02.IQYER# = 2014    

Gives duplicate data:

 AB25X5CL         2.5x5x1 CLEAR ACRYLIC BASE          CAC        EA          REC
 AB25X5CL         2.5x5x1 CLEAR ACRYLIC BASE          CAC        EA          REC
 AB25X5CL         2.5x5x1 CLEAR ACRYLIC BASE          CAC        EA          REC
```

Comment: It makes sense that types of parts will be sold multiple times. The table data would seem to indicate that it's not inventory but items that the store carries in general, and the price to it. As such, if you look at the data in the sales table, you'll likely see that 3 of these items were sold. Nothing looks out of sorts on your join.

Comment: Please, in the future, include column headers for all data you provide, so we know what you're talking about.  The question now becomes one of determining what a "unique" row for `ICSUM1` looks like, or how to get one.  2 notes - 1) get rid of the `ALL` keyword before the `SELECT` list, it doesn't do anything (you might exchange it for `DISTINCT`, as this would get a unique result row, but it's not clear if this would be the best/correct solution) 2) You don't actually have a `LEFT JOIN` - the fact you compare a column from that table in the `WHERE` clause is changing it to an `INNER JOIN`.